# Android Studio, image view,

Tags: android, mysql, android-imageview

I am pulling images from a MYSQL db and want to display the images in the App in a scroll-able view, something like the following is what you'd see on the screen:

image  image  image

image  image  image

image  image  image

And then there would be images that you can scroll down to view.  What would be the best way to do this?  Also, the number of images being pulled from the DB can vary so there can't be a set number of imageViews for the pictures.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: use a grid view

Comment: @CharukaSilva would it matter that I do not always know the number of images I am going to display?

Comment: it doesn't matter you can specify a width and a height for each or specific views if you want and number of views per raw and it populates

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this : [image](http://ghorbanzadeh.me/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Screenshot_2016-12-12-01-40-47.png)

If yes you should use Recycler view with gridlayout manager .

Follow [this sample code](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) completely .

And just replace this :

```
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
```

With :

```
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(con, 3);
```

hope it was helpful .

Comment: I will try it and get back to you

Comment: @houston Let me know if you have a problem !